# Extract data according to certain criteria

Tags: r

Hello I have to extract data according to certain criteria, but I have no idea how to do it.
I have patients who have had one or more hospital stays. The order of dates for each patient is done in an increasing order, i.e. date 1 comes before date 2 and the latter before date 3.
The numbers of the stays have no order, it's just random.
The diagnoses are coded by specialty (an organ system) and by disease (in my case it's ICD-10).
I.e. all `"A"` are diseases related to a an organ system (so they belong to a speciality). even though `"A01"` and `"A02"` are different diseases.

Here is a representation of my database.

```
Patient_ID<-c(rep("A",4),rep("B",3),rep("C",2),rep("D",2),rep("E",6),rep("F",3),"G")
Stay_ID<-c(paste("A",1:4,sep=""),paste("B",1:3,sep=""),paste("C",1:2,sep=""),
          paste("D",1:2,sep=""),paste("E",1:6,sep=""),paste("F",1:3,sep=""),"G2")
Date<-c(1,3,2,4,3,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,3,5,2,4,6,3,1,2,1)
Diagnosis<-c("A01","A01","A02","N01","C01","C01","Z72","E01","F56","A01","A01",
             "B36","B36","B37","F13","F13","K12","A33","A33","B13","O24")

data<-data.frame(Patient_ID,Stay_ID,Date,Diagnosis)

print(data)

   Patient_ID Stay_ID Date Diagnosis
1           A      A1    1       A01
2           A      A2    3       A01
3           A      A3    2       A02
4           A      A4    4       N01
5           B      B1    3       C01
6           B      B2    1       C01
7           B      B3    2       Z72
8           C      C1    2       E01
9           C      C2    1       F56
10          D      D1    1       A01
11          D      D2    2       A01
12          E      E1    1       B36
13          E      E2    3       B36
14          E      E3    5       B37
15          E      E4    2       F13
16          E      E5    4       F13
17          E      E6    6       K12
18          F      F1    3       A33
19          F      F2    1       A33
20          F      F3    2       B13
21          G      G2    1       O24
```

My objective is to extract the first visit of each specialty for each patient.

For example, I have to extract in patient `"A"` only the diagnoses `"A01"` of date 1 (I drop the second `"A01"` and the `"A02"`), and the `"N01"` of date 4. For patient `"E"` I extract only diagnosis `"B36"` from date 1 (in specialty `"B"`,and drop the second `"B36"` and the `"B37"` ), diagnosis `"F13"` from date 2 (I drop the diagnosis `"F13"` from date 4) and diagnosis `"K12"`. For patient `"G"` I extract his only diagnosis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the Diagnosis column into two parts and extract the letter first. Then, you can select the rows that are not duplicate on the df consisting of only Patient_ID and first_letter. You may need to sort the data by date but I couldn't figure out if it is Stay_ID or Date. Assuming it is the Date column:

```
# Sort by Patient_ID and Date
data <- data[order(data$Patient_ID, data$Date), ]
# Extract the first letter
data$first_letter <- substring(data$Diagnosis, 1, 1)
# Remove duplicates
data <- data[!duplicated(data[ ,c("Patient_ID", "first_letter")]), ]
data

   Patient_ID Stay_ID Date Diagnosis first_letter
1           A      A1    1       A01            A
4           A      A4    4       N01            N
6           B      B2    1       C01            C
7           B      B3    2       Z72            Z
9           C      C2    1       F56            F
8           C      C1    2       E01            E
10          D      D1    1       A01            A
12          E      E1    1       B36            B
15          E      E4    2       F13            F
17          E      E6    6       K12            K
19          F      F2    1       A33            A
20          F      F3    2       B13            B
21          G      G2    1       O24            O
```

Comment: I was about to comment on the need for `data[order(data$Date),]` but looks like you saw that yourself.

Comment: @Ragip Gürlek the date is the column "Date" not stay_ID. Stay_ID is just to attribute a number to the stay, I think it is really not essential here

Comment: @Ragip Gürlek,having more ease with dplyr I referred to your codes to write those that seem to bring the same answer. But to be cautious I prefer to ask the opinion of a person who has more programming skills. `data2<-data%>%arrange(Patient_ID,Date)%>%mutate(
  first_letter=substr(Diagnosis,1,1))%>%distinct(Patient_ID,first_letter,.keep_all = T)`